# Copying selected text to java swing application as image

Tags: java, swing, outlook, clipboard

I need to copy selected text from outlook (2010) to a java swing application. Instead of showing content on that image, it creates a black image.

```
final BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
```

Above code works fine for images. But when I select a text from outlook 2010 (Swings treat it as image) or if I select text + image from outlook, it displays me black screen for text part (If image is also in clipboard, then it prints just fine)